# Error in creating sample DataFrame from Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create sample DataFrame as follows.

```
case class NumberClass(number: Int)
val numberRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5))
val numberDF = numberRDD.map{ number =>
  NumberClass(number)
}.toDF
```

However, the code above returns errors like below

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not     initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials when creating Hive client using classpath:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resurces.jar,
```

I read the error message but not sure what it's saying about.
Where is this error coming from?

Comment: That error seems unrelated to the code and more to the way that spark is setup on the machine.

Comment: @maasg Thank you for your comment. I got same error with different code now, so I believe you're right... Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: That could be many things. Spark setup? Hadoop version mismatch? Spark version mismatch?  I'd start by doing a clean install validated with some example code known to work. (like the classic wordcount from the spark docs)

Comment: Thank you for kind reply. The problem is now solved by clean installing of Spark. I